# Protect workbook, copied to new destination, with password

Tags: excel, vba

I put two of my codes together to make copy for archive.

This creates a copy:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs
```

I reprotect my main file.

How to add a new password on the new file?

```
Dim strBlockedPass As String
```

Do I need to use some other code than ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs?

```
Option Explicit
Const strPassword = "Athens"

Sub CopyWorkBook()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strBlockedPass As String
    Dim strDatum As String
    Dim strUser As String
    Dim FileOnly As String

    strBlockedPass = "WASD1#2#3"
    FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
    strDatum = Format(Date, "dd.mmm.yyyy_")
    strUser = Environ("Username")

    'to remove old Password
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect Password:=strPassword
    Next ws

    'To create a full copy
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\Users\kka\Desktop\" & strDatum & "_" & strUser & "_" & FileOnly

    'reprotect active WorkBook with old password, after ws.unprotect
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect Password:=strPassword
        ws.Cells.Locked = True

    'Protection is working with cell.range defined by symbols in row.3000.
    'Each cell from that range has one symbol
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Range("A:AA").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, 
    AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You can open the copy you saved and make whatever changes you need.

Comment: Yes, but i would like to set it with vba without my intervention. It should be made with that one macro. Without need to make all changes manuell in final file. It will be used for many excel files not only one. It will be to much to make those changes each time. I think it is possible somehow to make a copy of all sheets and to use protect command for all sheet before they will be saved.

Comment: I didn’t mean do it manually, but using VBA

Comment: Ehh thx now i know what you had in mind.... I can just unprotect it form actual password and set a new one before save as. Then that same once more. Unprotect and save with first password! Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Const strPassword = "Athens"

Sub CopyWorkBook()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strBlockedPass As String
Dim strDatum As String
Dim strUser As String
Dim FileOnly As String
Dim NewFN As Variant

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  strBlockedPass = "WASD1#2#3"
  FileOnly = ThisWorkbook.Name
  strDatum = Format(Date, "dd.mmm.yyyy_")
  strUser = Environ("Username")

  'to remove old Password
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Unprotect Password:=strPassword
Next ws

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Protect Password:=strBlockedPass
Next ws
  'To create a full copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\klaud\Desktop\" & strDatum & "_" & strUser & "_" & FileOnly & "_Protected" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Unprotect Password:=strBlockedPass
Next ws
'reprotect active WorkBook with old password, after ws.unprotect
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets


ws.Unprotect Password:=strPassword
ws.Cells.Locked = True

On Error Resume Next
ws.Range("A:AA").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
On Error GoTo 0
ws.Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True

Next ws

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```